# {"Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text"}

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever I run this query I get this error. 
Help is appreciated.

> {"Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text"}

this is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = cons.CreateCommand();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.CommandText = "update coffeeshop set Quantity=convert(varchar(MAX),Quantity)-" + t1.Text;

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If I take away the convert(varchar(Max) as it can be seen in code bellow:

```
 SqlCommand cmd1 = cons.CreateCommand();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd1.CommandText = "update coffeeshop set Quantity=Quantity-" + t1.Text;
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Then I get this error:

> {"Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int"}

Comment: What is the type of `Quantity` in your table? Also, what is the value of `t1.Text`?

Comment: Quantity type is text in my database table and the value of t1.text is depend on the user as this is an empty text box for user to insert a quantity which is then subtracted in my query as it can be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out assuming quantity is `varchar`:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "update coffeeshop set Quantity= Convert(int,Quantity)-" + t1.Text;
```

for `text` try this:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "update coffeeshop set quantity= Convert(varchar(max) , Convert(INT, Convert(varchar(max),quantity))- "+ t1.Text + ")";
```

Comment: {"Explicit conversion from data type text to int is not allowed."} This is the error I get

Comment: @khans See my edit. Should work for you with a slight variation if not exactly what i have written.